# PHP Joomla tag h1 as article title or browser page title or menu title

Tags: php, joomla

I'm using sourcerer extension to include php script into a module and I would like to insert a tag h1 that contains one of the following in sequence (if - else):

1. article title
2. browser page title (assigned in the menu)
3. menu title

So if an article title exist for that page, then print the article title, else print the browser page title (assigned in the menu) or else print the menu title.

Can someone write for me the PHP code I need to do thet?
If possibile I would not call (show) the joomla table with the prefix in the DB in the PHP script.

Thnaks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by your last comment, starting with: "If possible I would not..."?

Comment: Hi jonasfh I meant that int the php code I don't want something that refers to DB. Is that possible?